# How to refresh position on website using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website that reads from a MySQL database and displays the most recent data on a map. How can I make this data refresh on the website once a second? Do I need to put my AJAX code in a timer? Does the PHP script that queries the database need to be on a timer?

```js
var geojson;
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a)
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "b.php",
    async: false,
    data: {c: a},
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (d) {
      var e = JSON.parse(d);
      geojson = e;
      new L.GeoJSON(e);
      L.geoJSON([e], {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            fillColor: "#ff0505",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 5,
            weight: 1
          });
        }
      }).addTo(mymap);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: You put a timer around your Ajax call. Not your PHP script.

Comment: Wrap your code in a setInterval method

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? Where is your PHP code?

Comment: If you are using `datatype: 'json',` then you should not need to do `var e=JSON.parse(d);`

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.

Comment: You can routinely update the geoJSON variable, but unless something is somehow listening for it to change, doing so won't update your website.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the `async:false` option, since using synchronous AJAX calls is not a good practice.

Then you can keep track of the time before performing a request, and upon completion, and calculate the timeout accordingly:

```
var func = function(){
    var interval=5000;
    var start = new Date();
    $.ajax({})
   .always(function(){
       var end = new Date();
       var timeout = interval - (end-start) 
       var timeout = timeout < 0 ? 0 : timeout;
       setTimeout(func, timeout);
   });
};
func();
```

You can alternatively utilise [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#throttle) from `lodash`.

```
var func = _.throttle(function(){
   $.ajax({....})
   .always(function(){
      func(); 
   });
}, 5000);

func();
```

In both of the above cases, a request will be performed every 5 seconds, or upon request completion (in case it lasts more than 5).

Comment: That worked. It is getting the new values as they come in. However, it is no longer plotting the point. Console not showing any errors. hmmm

Answer (score -1):

You can compare data of latest dataresult and use with

```
setTimeout(function(){  
    yourfunction_name() 
}, 1000);
```